# how to check file_exists in Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

We are trying to use this functions but we don't get the proper solution.
how to check file_exists for images in Smarty.

like

```
[{$oSelection->getName()}] = name of images.

[{assign var="filename" val="<img src="[{$oViewConf->getImageUrl()}]Productimg/selectlists/color/[{$oSelection->getName()}].gif" alt="">[{$oSelection->getName()}].gif"}]
[{if $filename|file_exists}]
success
[{else}]
no success
[{/if}]
```

Thank you...

Comment: You want to do this in your Model, not in the view.

Comment: This will always fail cause the filename is wrapped in a img tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can check this by

```
if (file_exists($file)) 
{
    $path = $filename;
}else{
    $path = 'demo.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```php
{if file_exists($filename)}..{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `{if file_exists($filename)}`